# ACCESS SQL Unpivot, Crosstab, Transform?

Tags: sql, transform, crosstab, unpivot

I have a table that has 2 columns:

```
Product Nr.| Placement  
         1 | Place1  
         2 | Place 2  
         3 | Place 3
```

I am trying to transform so that Place 1| Place 2| Place3 is header of the new table and Product 1, 2 &3 would fall under each Placement.

Crosstab and Transform require the use of an aggregate function, while I simply need to Unpivot?

Comment: PIVOT with MAX as agg function

Comment: transform max([Product Nr.])
select [Product Nr.]
from Table
Group by [Product Nr.]
Pivot Placement;    However the Select [Product Nr.] would list the Products both horizontally and vertically, and I would need only horizontally under each Placement title.